# How to use getHours() in javascript (in this case)?

Tags: javascript, date, google-chrome-extension

I'm developping a chrome extension. In the console I display URLs and time spent in websites.

But I would like to have the date in format hours.minutes.secondes...Instead of I have the time in format like that 5202163202120623136520002145632100...I don't understand how can I use getHours() getMinutes() and getSecondes() in my case?

My contentscript

```
var lastPing = +new Date();

 function ping() {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
         domain: location.host,
         lastPing: lastPing
     }, function() {
         lastPing = +new Date();
         console.log('Ping envoyé');
     }); } setInterval(ping, 5000);
```

My background

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender,  sendResponse) {
     var domain = request.domain;
     var lastPing = request.lastPing;
     var time_elapsed = localStorage.getItem(domain) || 0;
     localStorage.setItem(domain, time_elapsed + (+new Date() - lastPing));
     });
```

Comment: rtfm.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Get the time component of the date string:

`new Date().toTimeString().substr(0, 8)`

Comment: Not a very good idea to parse a string interpretation when methods like `getHours()` are available.

Comment: Yes, I agree.. I wrote this suggestion since I thought `getHours()` is already apparent for him.

Comment: Well, I suggest expanding the answer, as-is it has little explanation and you're talking to a novice programmer.

Comment: I don't understand how can I use getHours() getMinutes() and getSecondes() in my case? thanks